# How to solve the following problem with integer programming?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, integer-programming

I have an optimization problem, simply:

We have $2$ facilities and $7$ shops such that each facility produces $2000$ TV a month and each shop needs at least $500,100,800,400,700,200,1000$ TVs per month. Transportation from facility $1$ to a shop costs $4$ dollars per TV and from facility $2$ to a shop costs $6$ per TV. So, I have to minimize cost and the conditions must be satisfied.

If I am not wrong, the constraints and objective function must be as below. However, I am not sure how to solve the problem with integer programming without using simplex method. Here is what I wrote:

$x_{ij}$ : Number of TVs transported from facility *i* to shop *j*.
 Then we have,

> minimize C = $\displaystyle 4\sum_{j=1}^{7}x_{1j} + 6\sum_{j=1}^{7}x_{2j}$
>
> $x_{ij} \ge 0$
>
> $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{7}x_{1j} \le 2000$
>
> $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{7}x_{2j} \le 2000$
>
> $x_{11} +x_{21} \ge 500$
>
> $x_{12} +x_{22} \ge 100$
>
> $x_{13} +x_{23} \ge 800$
>
> $x_{14} +x_{24} \ge 400$
>
> $x_{15} +x_{25} \ge 700$
>
> $x_{16} +x_{26} \ge 200$
>
> $x_{17} +x_{27} \ge 1000$

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a transportation problem. It can be solved through a simplified version of the simplex method. Hope the link helps.
http://orms.pef.czu.cz/text/transProblem.html

Since this is an unbalanced problem, a dummy destination will have to be taken.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't use the Simplex method, just think of

> $x_i$: what is shipped from the $i^{th}$ facility;
> $0≤x_i≤2000$ and $x_1+x_2$ ≥ 3700;
> Minimize $4*x_1+6*x_2$.
>
> Plot a graph with $x_1$ and $x_2$ axis, draw a few lines, that's it.

A shop does not care where the TV comes from, as far as there are 2000 from the 1st facility and 1700 from the 2nd facility.

### Hope this helps!